# Rails, sum the aggregate of an attribute of all instances of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Channel. The relating table has several column, for example clicks.

So `Channel.all.sum(:clicks)` gives me the sum of clicks of all channels.

In my model I have added a new method

```
def test
 123 #this is just an example
end
```

So now, `Channel.first.test` returns 123

What I want to do is something like `Channel.all.sum(:test)` which sums the test value of all channels.

The error I get is that test is not a column, which of course it is not, but I hoped to till be able to build this sum.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: can we see the implementation of the test method? Maybe this could be done at the DB level and save *a lot* of performances

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Channel.all.map(&:test).sum
```

Where clicks is a column of the model's table, use:

```
Channel.sum(:clicks)
```

Comment: Awesome that worked already. I edited my question because in fact it's even a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you can do

```
Channel.all.sum(&:test)
```

But it would be better to try achieving it on the database layer, because processing with Ruby might be heavy for memory and efficiency.

## EDIT

If you want to sum by a method which takes arguments:

```
Channel.all.sum { |channel| channel.test(start_date, end_date) }
```

Comment: I wish I could, but the value that test returns is a calculation with some other factors and more that just a simple value.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about here is two very different things:

[`ActiveRecord::Calculations.sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) sums the values of a column in the database:

```
SELECT SUM("table_name"."column_name") FROM "column_name"
```

This is what happens if you call `Channel.sum(:column_name)`.

[ActiveSupport also extends the Enumerable module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb) with a `.sum` method:

```
module Enumerable
  def sum(identity = nil, &block)
    if block_given?
      map(&block).sum(identity)
    else
      sum = identity ? inject(identity, :+) : inject(:+)
      sum || identity || 0
    end
  end 
end
```

This loops though all the values in memory and adds them together.

```
Channel.all.sum(&:test)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Channel.all.inject(0) { |sum, c| sum + c.test }
```

Using the later can lead to serious performance issues as it pulls all the data out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you do this.

```
Channel.all.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum + x.test }
```

You can changed the 0 to whatever value you want the sum to start off at.